# Is it possible to edit message body of all sent emails in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I am testing if it's possible to edit the html code of all the emails sent from wordpress. This is what I came up with until now:

```js
     add_filter('wp_mail_content_type', function( $content_type ) {
                    return 'text/html';
        });

    add_filter('wp_mail', 'my_wp_mail');

    function my_wp_mail($atts) {
    $atts['message'] .= '  <br/><div id="result">my text line here</div>';
    return $atts;
    }
```

The code above will add the line "my text line here" at the bottom, I am looking for a way to be able to replace the div using JavaScript with content form another page using:

```js
    <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                jQuery('#result').load('https://develop2020.000webhostapp.com/divdiv.html .myclass');
            });

    </script>
```

then the email to be sent. Is it possible to do this with JavaScript or does PHP have to be used? If it is possible, how can I pull a div from a url and add it to all emails?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

First of all, using JS inside an email is not possible.

Using Javascript to send or determine content of emails seems really cumbersome, since Wordpress sends emails through PHP. Javascript runs in a browser (when it comes to Wordpress) and not on a server, so somehow a page would have to be opened in a browser to send the emails if you would try to do it with JS. If something is done on the server, like sending emails, you want to use PHP.

As for a solution, it makes more sense to get the page inside `.load()` with curl (https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php) or `file_get_contents` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), and then making what you load with that part of an e-mail using the filter you used to add content to the bottom of the emails.

If you only want to use a part of the page that you've retrieved with curl/file_get_contents, you can select that part using DOMdocument from PHP:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_dom_parser_example.htm
https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: thanks, I found the solution above ...but tried to apply this solution to page that has div that gets loaded using ajax ..it didn't work

Comment: You're right, if the page has a div loaded by Ajax that you want to put into an E-mail, things become more difficult. You should check what kind of data the ajax call in the page returns. If its HTML and not JSON, you could try to do the Ajax call yourself with a php method and then fill the gap. If it's JSON, you could choose to get the data with php and then parse it yourself. To find the Ajax call in that page I open developer tools (`ctrl+shift+i`) in chrome and go to network tab and check the packets of type `xhr`.

Comment: thanks ....I am not familiar with ajax but checked the xhr and found that the respose is html and contain the div I wanted how can I capture the div from that ajax call ..

Comment: If you click the xhr request and go to its `Headers` tab, at the top you see the Request URL, which is the URL where the Ajax call gets its the div. But it may also be sending post/get data to get it, which you can see if you scroll to the bottom of Headers tab, named `Query String Parameters`. You can use this to get the div.

Comment: Just retrieve the URL (with possible get/post vars) with any of the PHP functions that get a URL, like `curl` / `file_get_contents` (and maybe `DOMDocument->loadHTMLFile`).

Answer (score 0):

I found this way this worked

```
add_filter('wp_mail_content_type', function( $content_type ) {
                return 'text/html';
    });

add_filter('wp_mail', 'my_wp_mail');

function my_wp_mail($atts) {

$url = 'https://develop2020.000webhostapp.com/divdiv.html';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$elements = $xpath->query('//div[@class="myclass"]');
$link = $dom->saveHTML($elements->item(0));


$atts['message'] .= $link;
return $atts;
}
```

it worksed but now the issue with the page I want to capture the div from the div get loaded using ajax ..so not sure there is a solution